# Allowing certain file types with PHP on my HTML form is not working

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form with PHP validation. I want to allow only certain file types as attachments, but nothing I've tried so far is working - I've looked through many other questions, but still hopeless. I tried adding validation, but right now, I get error message no matter what file type i insert..

```
$file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
  $allowed = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', txt');
    if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
      $attachment_error = 'Only jpeg, jpg, png, gif, pdf, doc, docx and txt files may be inserted.';
    }
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: First, last value "txt" is missing opening single quote. You should use editor that supports code highlighting.

Comment: You missed opening single quote ofan array's last value `$allowed = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'txt');`

Comment: `$file_type` contains the whole name of the file, not just the extension you wish to check against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. First, you have a typo in your array - `txt` is missing an opening single quote. Second, you're testing against the whole file name, not just the extension. Here is one way to fix the issue, explode the name and get the extension from the end of the name's array:

```
$file_name = 'foo.ini';
$file_name_parts = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_ext = end($file_name_parts);
$allowed = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'txt');

if(!in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
    $attachment_error = 'Only jpeg, jpg, png, gif, pdf, doc, docx and txt files may be inserted.';
    echo $attachment_error;
} else {
    echo 'found it';
}
```

**CAUTION:** This is not the most secure way to check a file's type, it is only a way to verify a file's extension. If you truly want to check the file type you should use PHP's [file info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) functions.

**EDIT:** From the comments it was found the `$_FILES['attachment']['name']` was an array, requiring the use of `$_FILES['attachment']['name'][0]` to get the actual file name prior to testing.

Comment: I still get the error no matter what file type I insert :/

Comment: what do you get when you `echo $file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];`?

Comment: It just echoes: Array

Comment: There is your problem. What if you `print_r($_FILES['attachment']['name']);`?

Comment: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )

Comment: It looks like your `$_FILES` array is empty. Did you submit the form? Can you add the form markup to your question?

Comment: Oh sorry, previously I submitted an empty form. If i add a file I get: Array ( [0] => FileName.docx [1] => [2] => [3] => )

Comment: So you have a way to upload multiple forms? Try the code with `$file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][0];`

Answer (score 0):

You can check `['type']` value instead of `['name']` , `explode()` string and use `$file_type[1]` for checking if in array.

```
  $file_type = explode("/", $_FILES['attachment']['type']);

  $allowed = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', txt');
    if(!in_array($file_type[1], $allowed)) {
      $attachment_error = 'Only jpeg, jpg, png, gif, pdf, doc, docx and txt files may be inserted.';
    }
```